# How to change text color of starting row in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'm trying to display a `UIPickerView` that has the selected row displayed in a unique text color.  So the selected row should be displayed in a red font, and all other (unselected) rows are displayed in a black/default font.

I have implemented this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UILabel *oldLabel = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:self.previouslySelectedRow forComponent:component];
    oldLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    self.previouslySelectedRow = row;
}
```

Which works when changing selections flawlessly, but does not do anything for the initial row that is displayed.

I am calling:

```
[pickerView selectRow:initialRow inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

After I display the `UIPickerView`, but I have realized that this does not result in `didSelectRow` being called (that only happens when the user changes the selection manually).

I have tried to set the `UILabel` `textColor` value myself - something like:

```
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewForRow:startingRow forComponent:0];
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But unfortunately that results in nothing happening.  I call this AFTER displaying the pickerview.

Is there some easy way of doing this? Am I missing something? Thanks for any/all help!

Zach

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself just recently working in Xamarin Monotouch (.net for iOS) I couldnt find a "clean" fix, but I made a very small hack which seems to work fine thus far. I will provide my solution in C#, apologies as I can read ObjC however I would only embarrass myself by trying to write it. You should get the idea pretty easy I hope.

- Override UIPickerViewDelegate. Add an int field, with which we will populate the index of the dataitem we need to select upon the picker controls first use.

  ```
  protected class PickerDelegate : UIPickerViewDelegate
  {
      // Contruction...overrides etc

      public int SelectIndexOnLoad { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Now in the area of code where you load/instantiate the pickercontrol (ViewDidLoad etc) locate the index of the datasource, which contains the data you want to display/select first in the picker.

  ```
      // First get the index value of the current set of data you
      // want to display, assuming here I have a list of items as my
      // picker datasource

      var x = this.items.IndexOf(data_value_to_display);

      // Then assign it to our PickerDelegate.SelectIndexOnLoad

      this.myPickerDelegate.SelectIndexOnLoad = x;
      this.myPickerView.selectRow(x, 0, true);

      // Note in Xamarin, the objc delegate call selectRow() is mapped to Select()
  ```
- In the pickerdelegates viewForRow() call (Xamarin objC call is mapped to GetView()) we compare the PickerDelegate.SelectIndexOnLoad to the passed row variable, and decide on UI values

  ```
      public override UIView viewForRow(UIPickerView pickerView, int row, int component, UIView view)
      {
          // Forget reusing the passed view
          // there is a bug in ios 7,8,9 which ensures its ALWAYS null, nice Apple!
          var view1 = new UILabel(predefined_rect_size);
          if (this.SelectIndexOnLoad == row)
          {
              view1.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Pink;
          }
          else
          {
              view1.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
          }

      // Optionally reset the SelectIndexOnLoad so that as the user moves
      // the picker (viewForRow is called constantly for redraws)
      // it goes back to normal color once moved.
      // If you want to keep it colored so the user knows the old original value
          // Simply omit this line
          this.SelectIndexOnLoad = row;

          return view1;

      }
  ```

This works fine, however, I dont like it. Im hoping an ObjC guru will enlighten us, but until then, this hack does the trick.
Kindest Regards

Answer (score 0):

## 3 things to check

## 1. where is ‘pickerView.selectRow’ called ?

it shouldn’t be called in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear
Instead place them in viewDidLayoutSubviews (prefer) or viewDidappear
to give some time for
    pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int ..)
to return all the UIView

(for iphone6 and later, if you place it in viewDidLayoutSubviews,
add 'self.yourPIckerView.layoutIfNeeded()' before selecting row)

## 2. didSelectRow should be called manually

‘pickerView.selectRow’ doesn’t automatically trigger didSelectRow.
After the line, place this to manually trigger it.
    self.pickerView(self.yourPickerView, didSelectRow: row, inComponent: comp)

## 3. animated parameter should be ‘false’

‘pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: comp, animated: false)’

If it’s ’true’, it will take some time for the picker to eventually get to the row you manually selected
and color change could be ignored by the delay